# Get the bare socket fd from a Twisted protocol in python?

Tags: python, sockets, twisted

What I would like to do is combine Twisted with the Cmd module in python's stdlib.

In short I would like to be able to get the bare-bones socket fd object from a connected Protocol to use as the stdin of the cmd.Cmd module in the stdlib.

In Long, My client that interfaces with my server uses the Cmd module to process commands and send those commands to the server.

On my server I would also like to use the same command processing method with the builting Cmd module. To do this i would need to specify the stdin and stdout of the command interpreter.
I could do this easily with the builtin sockets module, but i would like to do it with twisted if possible.

Here is some code to do what i want with plain sockets:

(Works with telnet)

```
# server
import socket
import cmd

class CmdProcessor(cmd.Cmd, object):
    def __init__(self, sock, addr):
        network = sock.makefile()
        super(CmdProcessor, self).__init__(stdin=network, stdout=network)
        self.sock = sock
        self.addr = addr

        # Run the cmd.Cmd processing loop
        self.cmdloop()

    def do_sayhi(self, args):
        # When 'sayhi' is recieved over the socket,
        self.sock.send("Hey yourself!")

    def do_quit(self, args):
        self.sock.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 2319))
    server_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_sock.listen(5)

    sock, addr = server_sock.accept()
    print("Connection accepted")
    connection = CmdProcessor(sock, addr)
```

This is *almost* what i want to to do. I just typed this up quick so i may be missing somthing. Half of it works. Currently, if you telnet into the server like:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 2319
```

And you send 'sayhi' nothing happens. But if you type 'sayhi' at the terminal you started the server from (There is a (Cmd) prompt) the output goes to the telnet client. So the stdout of the cmd.Cmd is working. But not the stdin. That probably has something to do with the fact that telnet sends CR-LF ('\r\n') by default. Where the cmd module may just listen for \n.

So how can get the fd or file object from a protocol in twisted to do what i am trying do achieve here with bare sockets?

And any insights on what the input from telnet connected to the server is not registering with the CmdProcessor?

Any advice, tips or pointers welcome. (Wait no, no pointers.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that instead you might want to look at [Manhole](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/demo_manhole.tac).

In general, the point of Twisted is **not** to use Python socket objects directly.  That's a big part of Twisted's job.  When you want to interact with the network using Twisted, you use Twisted's APIs instead - protocols and transports, if you're thinking about the lowest level.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the referral to Manhole. Yeah I know it kind of defeats the point to use plain sockets and twisted at the same time. I'm just learning Twisted, and wondered if it could be done. Plus i needed something with an fd or fileno() To use as stdin and stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You can add use_rawinput = False

```
class CmdProcessor(cmd.Cmd, object):
    use_rawinput = False
    def __init__(self, sock, addr):
    ....
```

This produces response for sayhi from telnet

Comment: Thanks! That solved one of my problems. But it should be: self.use_rawinput = False

Comment: Oh, nvm, i see where you put it. (Above the __init__, that works :)